# Installing Node, Bower and Bower Components on TFS Build Server using TFS Build 2015

Tags: node.js, gulp, bower, tfsbuild, tfs-2015

As a part of our TFS build process, we have to install node components including bower and run bower to get the required client side libraries. Then we have to run gulp to perform a bunch of other tasks.
But when I try to install bower and then perform bower install either as a Post-build event or Gulp task, I get the error

```
##[error]call npm install
##[error]call npm install bower
##[error]call bower install
##[error]call gulp"
```

Error: Can't install! `bower` doesn't seem to be installed.

We deploy to our TFS Build server using a service account. We cannot login to the server using the service account.

Comment: Do you mean you want to install Node.js with npm, and install Bower during TFS build? Could you share your steps?

Comment: I think i was able to install node to our build server using my personal account, which installed it "globally" to the machine, and thus npm was available to the build service (running as a service account).  I did not install node when RDP'ed into the server as the service account (though I *did* do that for Visual Studio)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try using the NPM task in the TFSBuild script.

Documentation for it can be found here

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/Library/vs/alm/Build/steps/package/npm-install